# Check if a boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object is empty?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

[`boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.html) can be constructed with the default constructor, which creates an empty `shared_memory_object` (i.e. one that has no shared memory owned by it).  Depending on the situation, my code might construct a `shared_memory_object` that is empty.  This means that sometimes I would need to check if a given `shared_memory_object` is empty.

While this seems like something that's really easy to do, nowhere in the documentation does describe how to test a `shared_memory_object` for emptiness!

I've looked at the code, which suggests that `shared_memory_object::get_name()` returns an empty C-string when there is no associated shared memory, but nowhere does it seem to guarantee that I will never get the empty C-string when shared memory is associated.  Furthermore, `shared_memory_object::get_size()` might return false even if there is associated shared memory, if the size cannot be obtained, so this method can't be reliably used either.

What is the proper way to test a `shared_memory_object` for emptiness?

Comment: You could try passing empty strings to the other constructors and then see what you get in `get_name()` : if you get a non-empty string, it means it will be empty only for the default constructor and you're good to go.

Comment: @OlivierSohn That feels dangerous.  Also, the implementations for are different for POSIX systems as compared to Windows and other systems, so what works on one system might not work on another...

Comment: that's a first step, then you can check all implementations and verify that the guarantees hold in all cases...